# Make Jquery hover script more efficient

Tags: jquery, hover

This is my first question so please be gentle. I have written a script to change a picture based on the text that I hover over but I know my script looks like it was written by a grade schooler. I'm in jQuery infancy but if you guys can help me make it cleaner and not so repetitive, that would be great. Thanks. 
Here is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tragicwhale/ab7ppo5g/2/) code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.small li:nth-child(1)').hover(function() {
     $('.inner img').attr('src', 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/niX/o44/niXo44qbT.png');
   });
   $('.small li:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
     $('.inner img').attr('src', 'http://www.i2clipart.com/cliparts/8/c/9/1/clipart-plane-8c91.png');
   });
   $('.small li:nth-child(3)').hover(function() {
     $('.inner img').attr('src', 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/niX/o44/niXo44qbT.png');
   });
   $('.small li:nth-child(4)').hover(function() {
     $('.inner img').attr('src', 'http://www.i2clipart.com/cliparts/8/c/9/1/clipart-plane-8c91.png');
   });
   $('.small li:nth-child(5)').hover(function() {
     $('.inner img').attr('src', 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/niX/o44/niXo44qbT.png');
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your jQuery you will need some other means of indicating which image goes with which `li`. There are several ways of doing that, but one would be to use a `data-` attribute on the `li` nodes:

```
<li data-hoverimg="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/niX/o44/niXo44qbT.png">
```

This way, you could simply write:

```
$('.small li').mouseover(function() {
  $('.inner img').attr('src', $(this).data('hoverimg'));
});
```

Comment: That worked beautifully David, Thanks a lot for your help. I'll be looking more into the data- attribute. I wish I could give you a vote. Thanks again.